# Using LIKE with a list

Tags: postgresql

I need to select records where a column value is LIKE any of the values an a list:

```
select * 
from bulkjob
where bulkjob_owner LIKE (
    SELECT '%' || sys_user_login
    FROM sys_user
    WHERE sys_user_type_id IN (3, 4, 5)
)
```

This doesn't work:

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Is there a way to accomplish this, maybe using Postgresql functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does a cross product, so you could get duplicates if the suffixes (ie sys_user_login names overlap: say 'joe' and 'marry-joe'). So you may need to do a distinct, or subquery.

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM bulkjob b
      ,sys_user s
  WHERE b.bulkjob_owner LIKE '%' || s.sys_user_login
    AND s.sys_user_type_id IN (3,4,5)
```

Comment: +1 You solved it. But explicit JOINs are the canonical way. `...    JOIN sys_user s ON b.bulkjob_owner ~~ ('%' || s.sys_user_login) WHERE s.sys_user_type_id IN (3, 4, 5);`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I guess I should start getting in the habit of doing that. Never really used the explicit JOIN statement until I came across threads here on SO. Some of the threads on the subject seemed like religious wars, but I do think the arguments in favour of using JOIN are convincing, especially for bigger statements. I'll work on it. Thanks.